# high cpu usage when executing scripts on rhel 7 VM coming from rngd

Tags: rhel, vmware, random

I'm moving a physical server to a VM (rhel 7.3) and while running a fairly basic script I noticed that CPU usage was very high for what I was executing. After a little investigation I found that if I run any script that rngd consumes about 30% CPU (30% over 4 cores, so one full core essentially). A test script that exhibits this behavior is as simple as this ...

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in {1..10000}; do
    echo $i > /dev/null
    y=$((i+1))
    echo $y > /dev/null
    echo $y | grep 'orange' > /dev/null
    sleep 0.001
done
```

I did a little research and it seems that vmware uses virtio_rng, a kernel module that exposes the hardware-based rng to the VM, and the module is loaded. I am not able to check if the configuration is correct on the esxi box itself but my questions are:

1. How can i ensure that virtio_rng is setup correctly in the virtual environment?
2. Why would such a simple script, which doesn't use random numbers, be accessing rngd and consuming essentially an entire cpu?
3. I may not understand entropy and how it plays a role when executing commands. Can someone point me in the right direction? (google yielded a lot of non-applicable results)